Facing issue while integrating Jitsi Meet in my Flutter application
I am trying to create a flutter application for video conferencing similar to Zoom. So, I am integrating Jitsi Meet in my flutter application. I have used jitsi_meet_flutter_sdk package to use Jitsi Meet.
Link - https://pub.dev/packages/jitsi_meet_flutter_sdk
After configuring it for my android application, I am unable to create a meeting. Whenever I am trying to create a meeting, it is asking me to Wait for moderator or Log-in. I have already authenticated to my application using Google Auth.(https://i.sstatic.net/oTBCTWrA.jpg)
Code -
`import 'package:../resources/auth_methods.dart';
import 'package:../resources/firestore_methods.dart';
import 'package:jitsi_meet_flutter_sdk/jitsi_meet_flutter_sdk.dart';

class JitsiMeetMethods {
  final AuthMethods _authMethods = AuthMethods();
  final FirestoreMethods _firestoreMethods = FirestoreMethods();

  void createMeeting(
      {required String roomName,
      required bool isAudioMuted,
      required bool isVideoMuted,
      String username = ''}) async {
    try {
      var jitsiMeet = JitsiMeet();

      String name;
      if (username.isEmpty) {
        name = _authMethods.user.displayName!;
      } else {
        name = username;
      }
      //var options = JitsiMeetConferenceOptions(room: roomName);
      var options = JitsiMeetConferenceOptions(
        serverURL: "https://meet.jit.si",
        room: roomName,
        configOverrides: {
          "startWithAudioMuted": isAudioMuted,
          "startWithVideoMuted": isVideoMuted,
          "subject": "Jitsi With Flutter",
        },
        featureFlags: {"unsaferoomwarning.enabled": false},
        userInfo: JitsiMeetUserInfo(
          displayName: name,
          email: _authMethods.user.email,
        ),
      );
      _firestoreMethods.addToMeetingHistory(roomName);
      await jitsiMeet.join(options);
    } 
    catch (err) {
      print("Error:$err");
    }
  }
}`

I am expecting that it should create a new meeting with a new meeting id randomly generated and the person creating the meeting(i.e. first person or host) should automatically be the moderator.

Change the serverURL
serverURL: "https://meet.jit.si",
To
serverURL: "https://meet.ffmuc.net",
It will work.
